# Why can't I use "%[^\n]" scanset?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

I'm trying to get user input for my string with spaces on my program but for some reason `%[^\n]` doesn't work.

The `%` part is marked red. I couldn't understand why. It just skips and doesn't ask for user input.

```
int prelim, midterm, semiFinal, final, totalScore, yearLevel, studentId;
float averageScore = 0;
char name[25], degree[25];

printf("Enter your student id: ");
scanf("%d", &studentId);
printf("Name: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);
printf("Degree: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", &degree);
printf("Year: ");
scanf("%d", &yearLevel);
```

Comment: In this format string `%[^\n]s` the `'s'` is not part of the format specifier but an extra character. Did you mean `%[^\n]` instead?

Comment: To avoid potential problems with buffering, you should add `\n` to your `printf` to trigger flushing of `stdout` before reading. Otherwise you might not see any output when you are waiting for input. Also you should not add `&` to array names. They automatically decay to a pointer when passed to a function.

Comment: Common newbie error: `%s` and `%[...]` are quite different format specifiers. The second is not a subset of the first. You also need a space before `%` to filter the previous newline left in the buffer, to limit the input length, and remove the `&`. So `scanf(" %24[^\n]", name);`. Ditto for `degree`. I recommend you spend at least one hour studying `scanf` in detail, using hands-on examples/tests. There is a great deal to take in, and its behaviour varies with each format specifier.

Comment: It worked now. I see where I made my mistake. Thank you all very much. I'm going to study a lot more. I just got into programming and this is really fun.

Comment: I'm going to offer a dissenting opinion to @WeatherVane's recommendation to spend time studying `scanf` in detail.  In the long run, `scanf` is useless.  Any time you spend studying it is time you're not spending learning how to [use something better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).  And you really want to learn something better, and wean yourself entirely off of `scanf` as soon as you are comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `scanf("%[^\n]s", &name)` must be `scanf("%[^\n]", name)` as

1. The `s` is not part of the `%[` format specifier as people new to C often think.
2. The ampersand should be removed as the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element which is already the type that `%[` expects.

Now, to answer your question, **`%[^\n]` will fail if the first character it sees is a `\n`**. For the `scanf` for `studentId`, you type the number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That `scanf` consumes the number but leaves the enter character (`\n`) in the input stream. Then, the `scanf` for `name` sees the newline character and since it's the first character that it sees, it fails without touching `name`. The next `scanf` fails for the same reason and the last `scanf` waits for a number.

But wait! Why doesn't the last `scanf` fail as well? The answer to that is certain format specifiers like `%d` skip leading whitespace characters. The `%[` format specifier does not.

Now how do we fix this? One easy solution would be to tell `scanf` to skip whitespace characters before the `%[` format specifier. You can do this by adding a space before it: `scanf(" %[^\n]", name)`. When `scanf` sees the space, it will skip all whitespace characters from the input stream until the first non-whitespace character. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I know where I made my mistake now. I'm going to study a lot more.